# Gradle - Run CustomTask Immediately after android apk creation

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My Customtask unzips the apk and collects sha1 for some file, so I have created my task but I want to execute it every time any apk(any built or any variant) is generated, dont know how to trigger my task exactly after apk is created. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this :

```
assemble.finalizedBy Customtask
```